# Why does the substitution $\cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} $ work?

Tags: real-analysis

This is an example from my textbook:
Function $z(x, y)$ satisfies
$$
z_{xx}'' + z_{yy}'' = 0
$$
Let  $ x = r\cos\theta $, $ y = r\sin\theta $, and $ w(r, \theta) = z(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) $
Then 
$$
\frac{\partial ^ 2 w}{\partial r ^ 2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial w}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \theta ^ 2}
$$

The proof basically said that by the chain rule one can easily derive that
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} \cos \theta - \frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} \frac{1}{r} \sin \theta
$$
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} \sin \theta - \frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} \frac{1}{r} \cos \theta
$$

So
$$
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial z} {\partial x} = (\cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}) (\frac{\partial w}{\partial r} \cos \theta - \frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} \frac{1}{r} \sin \theta)
$$
And after some work one can get the result.

What I don't understand is that why (rigorously) does the substitution
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
$$ work?

I know that operators are maps from functions to functions, but what does $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ do here? All the functions are in $r$ and $\theta$, what does it mean to take $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$?

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon this for quite some time. It is a common abuse of notation that is very useful in computations. You have to interpret it as follows: if you have a function $f=f(x)$ and a change of coordinates formula $$x=\Phi(r, \theta)$$ then you can form the expression of $f$ in the new coordinate system:
$$\bar{f}(r, \theta)=f(\Phi(r, \theta)).$$
The identity you are given then says that 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)=\left.\left(\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial r} -\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial \theta}\right)\right|_{x=\Phi(r, \theta).}$$
Since there is no ambiguity one usually drops all the additional notation and simply writes 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}-\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}.$$

Comment: Thanks! The identity make sense now. However, what does it mean to take $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ of a function $\bar{f}(r, \theta)$?

Comment: @leafpile: No sense. It is implicit that you have to change coordinates first. Note that $\Phi$, being a change of coordinates, is always assumed to be invertible (except at most in some singular points).  So $$\frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial x}=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \bar{f}(\Phi^{-1}(x)\right)\right|_{x=\Phi(r, \theta)}.$$